# Mapping between hourofday , dayofweek, monthofyear

Tags: java

I wanted to know what is the mapping of values between related day of week, hour of day and month of year of DateTime object (joda or java 8)and their respective values?

dayofweek

1: Monday..7 Sunday ?

HourofDay
1:12am 2 ?

MonthOfYear
1: January...12 December?

Is above mapping correct?

Comment: can you clearify your question and can you post your code, what you have tried so far

Comment: qour question is not clear described

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is what are the default values of different DateTime constants. According to [this page](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) the following constructor defination

> ```
> public DateTime(int year,
>                int monthOfYear,
>                int dayOfMonth,
>                int hourOfDay,
>                int minuteOfHour)
> ```
>
> Constructs an instance from datetime field values using ISOChronology
>   in the default time zone.  Parameters:  
> year - the year
>  monthOfYear -
>   the month of the year,  from 1 to 12 
> dayOfMonth - the day of the
>   month,  from 1 to 31 
> hourOfDay - the hour of the day,  from 0 to 23
>   
> minuteOfHour - the minute of the hour,  from 0 to 59  
> Since:
>   2.0

For dayOfWeek refer [this page](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html)

> ```
> public static final int MONDAY = 1;
> public static final int TUESDAY = 2;
> public static final int WEDNESDAY = 3;
> public static final int THURSDAY = 4;
> public static final int FRIDAY = 5;
> public static final int SATURDAY = 6;
> public static final int SUNDAY = 7;
> ```
>
> Accessing fields
>   
>   `DateTime.Property pDoW = dt.dayOfWeek();
>   strT = dt.dayOfWeek().getAsText();
>   iDoW = dt.dayOfWeek().get();`